# Is it possible to have Labels, Checkboxes and Comboboxes to have equal heights in a WPF XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, alignment

I'm working on a C# WPF application, containing some XAML files, which are based on `Label`, `Checkbox` and `ComboBox` controls inside a grid.

As those three controls have a different height by default, this makes my XAML quite ugly (rows, starting by a `Label` are larger than rows who only contain a `ComboBox`).

The difference in height can be seen here:

`Label` is slightly larger than `ComboBox`:

[image]

`ComboBox` is significantly larger than `CheckBox`:

[image]

Is there a way to:

- make sure all mentioned controls have the same default height?
- make sure some rows in a grid have the same height, without needing to use fix values (like `Height="10"`)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of extra information is needed in this question?

Comment: The visualization of elements (Control) is determined by their template. When changing the template, even elements that have the same dimensions may become different. Therefore, without setting your custom templates to all the elements you need, it is impossible to solve your problem.

Comment: yes it is possible. do you want to use style or template? I can make an example for you

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I've discovered the following style definition in the XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="...">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="..."/>
</Style>
```

As the margins had different values for different control types, this messed up my window.